# How to use `webpack` `require.include`?

Tags: javascript, webpack

After read the `webpack` doc about `require.include`, I still don't understand what does it mean. I write a demo, get the `bundle` file like this:

```
undefined/*! require.include ./a.js */;
__webpack_require__(/*! ./b.js */ 2);
```

As you can see, `require.include('./a.js')` do not execute the `__webpack_require__` function, `require('./b.js')` execute the `__webpack_require__` function.

What's the `require.include` meaning and how to use it in the real world?